# Can't public class Functions can also cause accidental change in data members?

Tags: c++, private

The main reason to make data members of a class private is to make it easy to trace bugs in the program or prevent accidental changes.

But public functions of the class can be called anywhere in the whole program and change the data members value. So wouldn't tracing bugs be as tedious as when making member public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that there's a single point in the code that actually *does* change the value, but does it on behalf of the code that wants it changed.

Quick example:

```
class A
{
public:
    void set_x(int x) { m_x = x; }
    int m_y;
private:
    int m_x;
};
```

Suppose we know that `m_x` and `m_y` should always be between -100 and 100, and  some bug is causing both to be 2000.

There are various ways of finding the code that causes the bug:

We can set breakpoints.
With `m_x`, we set one, in `set_x` - with `m_y`, we need to find *every* assignment to it throughout the code and set a breakpoint there (and someone may use a pointer or reference to it, so we can't just search for "m_y" - we need to find every *potential* assignment).

Or, we could insert some validation code and throw an exception when things go bad.
Just as before,  we need to do that in *one* place with `m_x`, but need to locate every potential reference to `m_y` throughout the code.

Comment: so basically we are able to make a single checkpoint for undesired changes in case of private member?

Answer (score 2):

This is true, and indeed you have an orthogonal tool supplied by the language which are `const` member functions.

A function declared as

```
public:
  void noSideEffects() const;
```

will generate a compile time error if the body of the function tries to modify a member of the class (or tries to invoke a method of that member which is not `const` in turn).

The concept of visibility of a method doens't have anything to do with its ability to modify the state of the object. It's perfectly legal to let a public method alter the state, otherwise they would be severely limited.

Comment: But what about the public functions that we are using to manipulate the data members? They would defeat the purpose of making the members private right?

Comment: No, because to modify the member you will have to pass by the method, you can't directly modify it (eg. `object->method = something`) so every time the field is set the method will have control in how it happens.

Comment: Exactly, but then in this case the only difference is that the method is modifying the member instead of us directly modifying it! So what advantage does that give us?

Comment: Data validation for one.

Comment: Yes data validation can be implemented through methods. But isn't there is a bigger picture to this?

Comment: I suppose another thing is that the changes to the data members are restricted. So there is only a particular set of changes that can be made on the data rather than any random types of changes